# How to exchange one specific value in an array in Julia?

Tags: arrays, replace, julia

I'm pretty new to Julia, so this is probably a pretty easy question. I want to create a vector and exchange a given value with a new given value.

This is how it would work in Java, but I can't find a solution for Julia. Do I have to copy the array first? I'm pretty clueless..

```
function sorted_exchange(v::Array{Int64,1}, in::Int64, out::Int64)
    i=1
    while v[i]!=out
        i+=1
    end
    v[i]=in
    return v
end
```

The program runs but just returns the "old" vector.
Example: `sorted_exchange([1,2,3],4,3)`, expected:`[1,2,4]`, actual:`[1,2,3]`

Comment: Your example returns `[1, 2, 4]` for me?

Comment: Really? For me it's like this:
`julia> sorted_exchange([1,2,3],4,3)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3`

Comment: Same for me, your example returns the expected, correct answer: `[1,2,4]`

Comment: Okay, now it's getting weird: If I try using the method in the IDE (Atom/Juno), it doesn't work, but if I put the exact same code in the shell, it works just fine. Well thanks either way

Comment: It works for me in Juno as well... I would ask what Julia version and OS you're on, but I can't think of anything in your example that would have been affected by changes of Julia verions.

Answer (score 4):

There's a nice built-in function for this: `replace` or its in-place version: `replace!`:

```
julia> v = [1,2,3];

julia> replace!(v, 3=>4);

julia> v
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 4
```

The code you have posted seems to work fine, though it does something slightly different. Your code only replaces the first instance of `3`, while `replace!` replaces every instance. If you just want the first instance to be replaced you can write:

```
julia> v = [1,2,3,5,3,5];

julia> replace!(v, 3=>4; count=1)
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 4
 5
 3
 5
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the value you want to replace using `findall`:

```
a = [1, 2, 5]
findall(isequal(5), a) # returns 3, the index of the 5 in a
```

and use that to replace the value

```
a[findall(isequal(5), a)] .= 6
a # returns [1, 2, 6]
```

Comment: To do what the example code is doing, wouldn't it be better to use `findfirst` instead of `findall`?